# How to loop the input type text?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I loop the input type text so that it can have it's own unique attribute eg. name, value. What I mean is that for example name="text1", name="text2",. Something like that. Here is my code. Thanks :)

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE></TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function add(type) {

        //Create an input type dynamically.
        var element = document.createElement("input");

        //Assign different attributes to the element.
        element.setAttribute("type", "text");
        element.setAttribute("value", "typhere");
        element.setAttribute("name", "txtbox");

        var btns = document.createElement("input");


        btns.setAttribute("type", "button" );
        btns.setAttribute("value", "delete");
        btns.setAttribute("name", "dlete");


        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

        //Append the element in page (in span).

                foo.appendChild(element);
                foo.appendChild(btns);
                var br = document.createElement("br");
                foo.appendChild(br);

    }
    </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <FORM>
    <H2></H2>

    <BR/>


    <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].value);"/>

    <span id="fooBar"><br/></span>

    </FORM>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: So, you mean each time someone clicks the button, the add function is executed, and each time you'd like it to use a different sequential number for the ID of the created elements?

Comment: First of all i'd take the JavaScript out of the HTML tag, and that will make it easier to make it more robust. Then bind that to the 'click' event for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that :

```
var inputId = 0;

function add(type){
   // do the stuff you have to do with inputId
   // input.setAttribute("name", "text" + inputId); for example
   inputId++;
}
```

If you do not want to pollute global namespace you can do :

```
(function(window){
  var inputId = 0;

  window.InputManager = {
     add : function(type){
         // do tuff with inputId
         // input.setAttribute("name", "text" + inputId); for example
         inputId++;
     }
  };
})(window);
```

and then

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="InputManager.add(document.forms[0].value)"/>
```

Comment: Your first solution is correct, sorry but I able to solve my problem before I read this. I havent tried your 2nd solution though :)

Comment: There is no problem, I'm glad that your script works now ;) 
My second solution is quite the same as the first one, but hide the variable `inputId` from the global namespace, and put the `add` function into a new one (*InputManager*) so this function does not appear in the global namespace neither.

Answer (score 1):

```
     var i=1;
   function add(type) {

    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");

    //Assign different attributes to the element    
   element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", "typhere"+i);
    element.setAttribute("name", "txtbox"+i);

    var btns = document.createElement("input");


    btns.setAttribute("type", "button" );
    btns.setAttribute("value", "delete"+i);
    btns.setAttribute("name", "dlete"+i);
    i++;
```

Use a variable i to increment the value.

Comment: Hi, I already did that, but it does not increment the variable. I dont know why..hmm

Comment: It doesn't increment the variable because "text1", for example, is not a valid `type` attribute for an `input` element. Also, there is no loop here. Unless I'm grossly misunderstanding the question here.

Comment: This is javascript... Is there a static keyword?

Comment: here is my code 
 var txtLoop = 1;
  
    var element = document.createElement("input");
   
   
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", "typhere");
    element.setAttribute("name", "txtbox" +txtLoop);
    txtLoop++;

Comment: use the var i outside the function.

Comment: that should do it.. My mistake in this code is the variable,. I placed it inside the function, where in it should be outside the function.

Comment: static word is reserved for future keyword by the ECMAScript specifications : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: below script tag doesnt matter you can use it outside anywhere within script tags

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var  counter=1;
function add(type) {

    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");

    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", "typhere"+counter);
    element.setAttribute("name", "txtbox"+counter);

    var btns = document.createElement("input");


    btns.setAttribute("type", "button" );
    btns.setAttribute("value", "delete");
    btns.setAttribute("name", "dlete");


    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

    //Append the element in page (in span).

            foo.appendChild(element);
            foo.appendChild(btns);
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            foo.appendChild(br);
            counter++;

}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kLJWW/